# Is it possible to make Spark UDF working with Array that could be None?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How to make this code working when array could be None :

```
def stringInArrayContains = udf((array: collection.mutable.WrappedArray[String], str: String) => array.filter(x => x.contains(str)).mkString(";"))
```

Comment: What array? the udf´s input array, the result array?. Spark sql types don´t understand option Scala types so you need to handle that in a different way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This UDF will just work fine, just make sure it's only called for inputs which are non null :

```
.withColumn("result",when($"arr".isNotNull and $"string".isNotNull, stringInArrayContains($"arr","string"))))
```

otherwise handle nulls inside UDF:

```
def stringInArrayContains = udf((array: collection.mutable.WrappedArray[String], str: String) => if(array==null || str==null)  null else array.filter(x => x.contains(str)).mkString(";"))
```